# Why do no external iPad/iPhone batteries charge via a dock connector?

Tags: iphone, ipod, battery, dock

There are many external battery packs which have a USB port for charging your iPad or iPhone on the go. But they all seem to be charged via a Micro USB port themselves, rather than a dock connector.

Why?

Is there some technical reason or does Apple not license the female dock connector?

Comment: Oy vey, why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, many do.  [Here's one example](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2010/12/13/incase-iphone-battery-case-offers-extended-battery-with-dock-connector/), and [here's another](http://store.fastmac.com/product_info.php?products_id=405).

The reason is probably licensing.  Apple charges a fee for [developing products using this connector](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/), and I believe there's also a very small per-port royalty (as with FireWire).

Comment: They're iPhone-only "battery cases", but it's a good start. Got a link for an external battery pack (~4000mAh) you can charge an iPad off?

Comment: Sure - I've used this one for a couple years; works well: http://www.newtrent.com/IMP50D-dual-USB-5000mAh-iphone-battery-p/imp50d.htm

Comment: Ah, that pack charges *itself* off Micro USB, which is not what I wanted. I want an external battery pack which charges itself from a dock connector socket.

Comment: What's the point, other than 1 less cable to carry and a higher product price?

Comment: ... and one less charger, which is a pretty big point.

Comment: Not necessarily so.  The NewTrent device comes only with a USB cable, and works off the iPad's charger.

Comment: Good to hear. But I would still prefer that one less cable, if only then for aesthetic (in the very Apple-esque "not just how it looks" sense) reasons.